# Child objects not being populated only when using SQLite (Works in SQL Server)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Fluent NHibernate mapping that works as expected when I run it against the actual SQL Server database but that is not populting a collection of child objects when run against SQLite. The structure that is being queried is a self-referential account hierarchy where each account may have one parent and 0-M child accounts. The parent account is getting loaded correctly, but the list of child objects is always coming back `null`.

The basic table structure looks something like this (**Note:** I've left out most of the fields that don't have anything to do with this issue.)

```
Account
-------
AccountID
Title
ParentAccountID
```

The Account class looks like:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Account ParentAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Account> ChildAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping for the Account class looks like:

```
public class AccountMap : ClassMap<Account>
{
    public AccountMap()
    {
        Table("Accounts");

        Id(a => a.ID).Column("AccountID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(a => a.Title);
        HasMany<Account>(a => a.ChildAccounts)
            .Table("Accounts")
            .KeyColumn("ParentAccountID")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("AccountID")
            .OrderBy("Title")
            .Inverse();
        References<Account>(a => a.ParentAccount).Column("ParentAccountID");
    }
}
```

The data in the Accounts table in the SQLite database when I'm trying to retrieve the account id:

```
ID        Title        ParentAccountID
--        -----        ---------------
1         Account1     null
2         Account2     1
3         Account3     2
4         Account4     2
```

When I make the call `session.Get<Account>(2)` I get back the following object:

```
{
    ID: 2,
    Title: "Account2",
    ParentAccount: 
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: "Account1",
        ParentAccount: null,
        ChildAccounts: null
    },
    ChildAccounts: null
}
```

Running the same call against the real SQL Server database return:

```
{
    ID: 2,
    Title: "Account2",
    ParentAccount: 
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: "Account1",
        ParentAccount: null,
        ChildAccounts: 
        {
            ID: 2,
            Title: "Account2",
            ParentAccount: 
            {
            ...
            },
            ChildAccounts:
            {
            ...
            }
        }
    },
    ChildAccounts: 
    [
        {
            ID: 3,
            Title: "Account3",
            ParentAccount: 
            {
                ID: 2,
                Title: "Account2",
                ParentAccount: 
                {
                ...
                },
                ChildAccounts:
                {
                ...
                }
            },
            ChildAccounts: null
        },
        {
            ID: 4,
            Title: "Account4",
            ParentAccount: 
            {
                ID: 2,
                Title: "Account2",
                ParentAccount: 
                {
                ...
                },
                ChildAccounts:
                {
                ...
                }
            },
            ChildAccounts: null
        }
    ]
}
```

I really don't understand why this would be working in SQL Server but not in SQLite, but it makes writing test to make sure that my mappings and repository code works correctly, very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to profile the sqlite db using sql profiler? I'm assuming that the profiler works with sqlite but I've never tried it.

Another thing to look at would be the nhibernate log file. Usually when I have problems like this these two tools is where I start.